# Ticks are inconsistent and are fluctuating

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, debugging, time, stopwatch

I have a sub and a button. And the code is like this:

```
Private Sub plus(ByRef a As Integer)
    For i = 0 To a
        a = a + a
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer = 19
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    sw.Start()
    plus(i)
    sw.Stop()
    MsgBox(sw.ElapsedTicks)
End Sub
```

when I run the sub is by clicking the "button1" the program to output 310 thats means 310 is sw.elapsedticks

When I run the sub again by clicking the "button1" again, the program to output 1 << JUST ONE ellapsedticks

How can it be like that ?

I tried to stop my vb.net program and I run it again, and then I click its button again, it happened the same, which is worth 272 stopwatch elapsedticks then after I click again stopwatch , elapsedticks instead be 1 again

Please explain why it could happen?

Comment: I assume the reason is something to do with the code in the `quicksort` method.

Comment: really ? I tested again in new project vb.net and I make very simple sub. The same problem occurred !! When I call the sub certain, It take 200 ticks because the sub very simple. And when I call that sub again, it take just 3 ticks.

Comment: Then edit your question to include your very simple sub. As it is, it is lacking the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that is needed in order for your question to be answered.

Comment: @SamuelRicky what are you trying to accomplish here? I really can't comprehend the logic you have above. Your calling method takes a reference object (argument), but you are not doing anything with it? Please ***explain what you are trying to accomplish here***...

Comment: @Zaggler You can see above, When I call a sub, it takes a little longer times, and when I call a same sub again, it takes very fast times.

Comment: @Zaggler And I just search a solution here how to call a sub at first in fast times like a second call

Comment: @Samuel Ricky I have some information I will post as an answer. I should have something up hopefully within the hour. This is a good question as well. I found the problem and it's going to take a little to post it, bear with me...

Comment: I guess it has to do with CPU Caching. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146797/Fast-and-Less-Fast-Loops-in-C) is a terrific article. For our case, especially the **Background** section.

Comment: Before a method can start running, it first has to be just-in-time compiled from the MSIL in the assembly to machine code that the processor can execute.  That happens just one, the first time you call the method.  You are seeing the time needed by the jitter to get that job done.  Experiment with the ahead-of-time compiler (Ngen.exe) to see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `StopWatch` class will fallback to using `DateTime` class and uses ticks for the measurements if your hardware doesn't support high-performance counter. Most computer's now day's, at least from Windows 2000 and later, have high-performance counters. With this in mind, the .NET `Stopwatch` class is based on this high frequency timer. In general, calling `Start` queries the performance counter and stores the value. When you `Stop`, it queries the performance counter again. Then the elapsed time is a simple subtraction of those two values to give you your `ElapsedTicks`.

> **Here are a few items to have a look at for further explanation...**

This property just makes a call to `GetRawElapsedTicks()`

```
  public long ElapsedTicks { 
        get { return GetRawElapsedTicks(); }
  }
```

The below function returns the actual time that has elapsed from the time the stopwatch was started to when the stopwatch `Stop` method was called. As mentioned above, `the elapsed time is a simple subtraction of those two values` you can see that below: `currentTimeStamp - startTimeStamp`.

```
 // Get the elapsed ticks.        
#if FEATURE_NETCORE
        public long GetRawElapsedTicks() {
#else
        private long GetRawElapsedTicks() {
#endif
            long timeElapsed = elapsed;

            if( isRunning) {
                // If the StopWatch is running, add elapsed time since
                // the Stopwatch is started last time. 
                long currentTimeStamp = GetTimestamp();                 
                long elapsedUntilNow = currentTimeStamp - startTimeStamp;
                timeElapsed += elapsedUntilNow;
            }
            return timeElapsed;
        }
```

Above you may notice the `#if FEATURE_NETCORE` and wonder what it is. These are called preprocessor commands. Basically they work like `if-else` statements except that if the condition isn't met it will not include the code at compile time as it's a pre-compile decision and not runtime...

With this all said, it was mentioned above already by Hans Passant about just in time (JIT) compiling. All of this I mentioned above breaks this down further for explanation. The real reason for the ***difference*** is the time it is taking for it to compile and run the ***first time***.

Another thing to mention. The `stopwatch` class uses a `long` variable type to store what they call `frequency`. Frequency" stores the frequency of the high-resolution performance counter if one exists, otherwise it will store TicksPerSecond. ***The frequency cannot change while the system is running, so it's only initialized once.***

Below are other `constants` that have a great deal with frequency and how it's calculated as well.

```
 private const long TicksPerMillisecond = 10000;
 private const long TicksPerSecond = TicksPerMillisecond * 1000;
```

When you create a new instance of the `StopWatch` class this is what is ran.

```
bool succeeded = SafeNativeMethods.QueryPerformanceFrequency(out Frequency);            
            if(!succeeded) {
                IsHighResolution = false; 
                Frequency = TicksPerSecond;
                tickFrequency = 1;
            }
            else {
                IsHighResolution = true;
                tickFrequency = TicksPerSecond;
                tickFrequency /= Frequency;
            }
```

Frequency as you can now see , has a big role in setting up ***how the elapsed time*** is going to be calculated and how often the `tick` is going to occur. Even when you stop your application it doesn't matter as the frequency is stored at this time. The only way to ***reset the frequency*** is to reboot your machine.

Comment: What does all of this about frequency have to do with the question? He isn't asking how the Stopwatch class works, he's asking why he sees the difference in times upon successive calls to a method. The only paragraph here that actually answers that question is the one where you make reference to Hans's comment.

Comment: @CodyGray it has a lot to do with the question. It's not just about the first time the method runs. It uses the frequency that is stored the first time it was ever ran period. I explained that in my post. If you read the last part I explain this. Try it yourself, the first time that class is instantiated it stores the frequency. Anytime after running the same thing the time greatly reduces. It doesn't ***matter if the method is clicked once***. You can stop the application and run it again and the results are still lower! Why it's because it looks at the frequency that was stored!

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. On the first creation on a Stopwatch class instance, its static constructor has to run, which takes time. That is true enough (in fact, static ctors are very slow in C# because the compiler does not optimize them well), but this initialization will not affect the timing measurements because the start time is not recorded until the `Start` function is called. His code simply measures the elapsed time between `Start` and `Stop` (which is effectively the time it takes to call the function `plus`).

Comment: Yes, if you run this on a rebooted machine you'll get very very high tick count. Anything after it's based on the current frequency. Look it up, **GetTimeStamp** it's in the reference that Microsoft has. The first block I posted makes a call to this... At least new machines support the high frequency older machines the code reaches out to the  Datetime...we are lucky ;)